# Использование библиотек в проектах

Tags: java, android, библиотеки

Хочется получить совет о том, насколько оправдано использование библиотек в проектах?

Я участвовал всего в одном более-менее серьезном проекте. В первом был наставник, который рекомендовал некоторые библиотеки для использования. Собственно, было указание - вопросов не возникало, сказано - сделано.

В настоящее время я работаю над проектом один, есть приложение на iOS, мне нужно реализовать на Android. Соответственно iOSник мне даёт какие-то советы и тд. Так вот, суть в том, что его приложение хотя и сложное, не использует библиотек. Все сам написал. Мне советует тоже самое сделать.

Когда я обращаюсь к гуглу то выходит, что для работы с сетью используйте `Volley`, если приложение работает с БД, то добавляйте в зависимости `GreenDao` или `ORMLite`, а когда задаешь вопрос по обработке событий, то в ответ слышишь:  "зачем изобретать велосипед, когда есть `EventBus`"!?

Мне, вроде бы, все нравится, но может тоже лучше будет взять библиотечку (легковесную, кстати), заплатить за нее один раз и обновлять иногда?

Ну или уже не париться и спокойно решать задачи, используя библиотеки?

**UPD**: В случае, если я могу решать своими силами вышеупомянутые задачи, использование библиотек обосновано. Но если я еще не успел овладеть этими знаниями? Не лучше ли будет, где можно попытаться сделать велосипед, чтобы получить знания, и потом осознано взяться за библиотеки?

Comment: Основное отличие популярных опенсорсных библиотек от ваших велосипедов: библиотеки довольно неплохо протестированы и отлажены, а ваш велосипед - нет.

Comment: Большинство андроид-библиотек - бесплатные. Остальное все уже сказали: быстро, просто, качественно. Можно придумать очень мало причин (да и те будут высосаны из пальца по большей части) почему бы нужно было отказаться от библиотек в пользу самостоятельного велосипедения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В современном мире без использования каких-либо библиотек не обходится ни одно более-менее серьезное приложение.
Другой вопрос, что бывает так, что качество библиотеки вас не устраивает (нет нужных функций, работает неправильно/неудобно и т.д., плохо расширяется). Тогда вы можете поискать аналоги или же попытаться написать свой "велосипед". Но "велосипед" нужно будет тщательно тестировать, поддерживать по мере развития, перехода на новую версию языка и т.д.
С другой стороны, однажды завязавшись на какую-либо библиотеку, вы будете вынуждены использовать её и дальше по мере развития проекта, что иногда приводит к сложным ситуациям. Например, сложность кастомизации какой-нибудь, на первый взгляд незначительной детали, которую вы не обнаружили в начале проекта, а в конце проекта это срочно понадобилось, и вам приходится городить кучу костылей.

В любом случае, библиотеки приучают и поощряют повторное использование кода, что является важным качеством для программиста и программ, которые он пишет.

Риторическое отступление:
даже банальный helloworld на Java будет использовать пакет System.out, который не является частью языка. Что уж говорить про коллекции, работу с файлами и т.д. Они являются частью стандартной библиотеки языка, таким образом, с формальной точки зрения, от использования библиотек вы никуда не уйдете.

**UPD:** Я считаю, что не нужно пытаться охватить всё, как вы предлагаете.  Предположим, что в вашем приложении должно быть шифрование данных, вы будете писать свою реализацию RSA? Для фотокамеры свой JPEG-компрессор? Для хранения данных свой JDBC и свою БД впридачу?
Если есть качественный инструмент, то почему бы им не пользоваться? Пользуясь библиотеками, вы уменьшаете вероятность ошибки в своем коде.

Answer (score 4):

В коммерческой разработке важно, что бы продукт выпустить побыстрее. А баги можно потом будет дофиксить (да, нужно выпускать без багов, но они такие, всегда пролезут). Поэтому в коммерческой разработке лучше сразу брать готовые проверенные библиотеки и делать работающий прототип.

А потом смотреть, если библиотека работает плохо - заменить другой или пофиксить саму библиотеку. Или если из библиотеки  нужна одна функция, а вес у нее - десятки мегабайт, тогда есть смысл переписать ручками.

А писать изначально все самостоятельно - накладно. В современном мире все очень быстро меняется. А печатать быстрее человек не всегда может.

> Так вот, суть в том, что его приложение хотя и сложное, не использует библиотек. Все сам написал. Мне советует тоже самое сделать.

А есть гарантия, что он сам все написал? может он накопировал код с чужих библиотек? Или если все написал сам, то покрыл всякие "краевые эффекты".

> Мне вроде бы все нравится, но может вместо меня тоже лучше будет взять библиотечку (легковесную, кстати), заплатить за нее один раз и обновлять иногда?

Если финансы позволяют, то почему и не купить (только желательно с полными сорцами. Без них крайне не рекомендую.).

Answer (score 3):

Для Android все вточности наоборот - используй библиотеки как можно чаще (если это, конечно, оправдано). насколько я знаю, в iOS библиотеки чаще всего распространяются без открытого исходного кода, или, еще хуже - платно. В Java все совершенно наоборот. Подавляющее большинство библиотек имеют открытый исходный код. Они отлично оптимизированы, и их настолько много, что можно найти библиотеку почти для любой задачи.

Кроме того, ИМХО первое правило (ленивого) программиста - научиться повторно использовать код (как свой, так и чужой)